# Is possible to add textbox on a FileCommonDialog?

Tags: c++, winapi

Just wonder if it is possible. 
In some case, it seems very convenient to add 1 or 2 controls on to common dialog box.

Now I want to add two textobx and 2 lable for image\s width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  It depends on what flavor of common dialog api you use.  For the newer Vista dialogs you can use the [IFileDialogCustomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM interface.  The AddEditBox() and AddText() methods are the ones you are looking for.

For the legacy XP compatible api functions like GetOpenFileName(), you can use OPENFILENAME.lpTemplateName and the OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE option to specify a dialog resource with the added controls.  Find guidance in this [MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).